# How do I sign an AMP update-cache request with Python's cryptography package?

Tags: python, amp-html, python-cryptography

How do I sign a URL for AMP's [update-cache API](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache) using Python's cryptography package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the core signature logic that will determine the path and query parameters for your update-cache request. Here, domain is the actual domain for your site, not the special AMP subdomain one.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

def sign_amp_update_cache_url(private_key: bytes, domain: str, url: str) -> str:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key, password=None)  # or whatever your key's password is
    message = f"/update-cache/c/s/{domain}{url}?amp_action=flush&amp_ts={int(time.time())}"
    binary_signature = private_key.sign(
        message.encode("UTF-8"),
        padding.PKCS1v15(),
        hashes.SHA256()
    )
    encoded_signature = base64.b64encode(binary_signature, altchars=b"-_").replace(b"=", b"").decode("UTF-8")
    signed_url = f"{message}&amp_url_signature={encoded_signature}"
    return signed_url
```

To finish preparing the request, you must [compute the AMP cache subdomain for your domain](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#amp-cache-url-format), get the [updateCacheApiDomainSuffix from caches.json](https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json), and concatenate the AMP cache subdomain, updateCacheApiDomainSuffix, and signed AMP update cache URL from the function above. [Here are Google's docs on the process with examples of what the cache URL should look like.](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache)